# Linux C application reading file that is being modified

Tags: c, file

I have a simple C application in Linux that opens a file with fopen and starts reading its contents, one line at a time, with fgets. While this is in process, a separate application overwrites the contents of that file, without locking it.

Is my application guaranteed to have access to the old contents of the file, and nothing from the new contents, as long as the file is not closed with fclose? A simple test with small files shows that the answer is 'yes', in that I have not been able to come up with instances in which it was not true. However, maybe with sufficiently large files and/or activity in them, such things will happen.

If anybody in this forum knows for sure one way or the other I would be very interested to know.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41668/what-happens-when-you-read-a-file-while-it-is-overwritten

Answer (score 1):

> Is my application guaranteed to have access to the old contents of the file, and nothing from the new contents, as long as the file is not closed with fclose?

**No**.

Your application does not have any guarantees that it will see the original contents of the file if the file changes.

> A simple test with small files shows that the answer is 'yes', in that I have not been able to come up with instances in which it was not true.

If you're using `fopen()`, the data is buffered.  Turn off buffering with [`setbuf(fp, NULL)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) and then try your test again.